# Re-organizing data to calculate sequence effects

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to use a specific order of a variable in a dataset - valence and - to essentially copy and paste rows into a new dataset. So, for each subID, for every valence = 0, if the next valence = -1 then copy that row to a new dataset called "sequence". The issue is that the trial order was randomized so the sequence is different for each subID (otherwise I'd at least be able to write a big blocky script based on trial number). One important thing I failed to initially mention: There will be a different number of values for each subID, so the number of rows are not even across subID's.

Just as an example of what the data looks like:

```
SubID location valence reaction_time
1     1        0       500
1     1       -1       600
1     0        1       400
1     0        0       500
2     1        1       700
2     1        0       400
2     0       -1       700
2     0        0       400
```

I'm pretty much a beginner at this kind of thing (I'm guessing it needs to be a loop?) and don't have a solid starting point, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your data is `d`:

```
out <- by(d, d$SubID, function(x) {
    v <- x$valence
    x[which(v[1:(length(v)-1)]==0 & v[2:(length(v))]==-1),]
})
sequence <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

Result:

```
> sequence
  SubID location valence reaction_time
1     1        1       0           500
2     2        1       0           400
```

Comment: Hi, I think I see (sort of) how the script works. But one thing I failed to mention is that the number of rows for each subID is different. I suspect that 's why I got this error?:`Error in tapply(seq_len(79155L), list(`factor(data$SubID)` = integer(0)),  : 
  arguments must have same length`

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't matter (I tried it out by amending your toy dataset). Is `length(factor(data$SubID))==nrow(data)`? (Also, I edited the answer because I just realized `factor(...)` is extraneous.)

Comment: `length(factor(data$SubID))==nrow(data)` returns FALSE

Comment: What does `data[setdiff(rownames(subset(data, select="SubID")), rownames(data)),]` give you?

Comment: Anyway, the other solution is quite elegant, so you might want to see if it works for you.

Comment: Embarrassingly it looks like I was making a small typo - subID was lowercase 's' - so the script you provided runs - however, it results in an empty dataframe (sequence returns 0 rows) - (which is actually the same issue I am having with the other script) - I will bother them now - thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It may be the case that `valence` is not a numeric object? What does `str(data)` report?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to subset your data.frame to rows 1 and 6. Here is a `data.table` solution.

```
# load library and change to data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# subset 
df[valence==0 & shift(valence == -1, type="lead"), .SD, by=SubID]
   SubID location valence reaction_time
1:     1        1       0           500
2:     2        1       0           400
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="SubID location valence reaction_time
1     1        0       500
1     1       -1       600
1     0        1       400
1     0        0       500
2     1        1       700
2     1        0       400
2     0       -1       700
2     0        0       400")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help - as I mentioned in my comment above I tried your script, but it returns `Empty data.table (0 rows) of 4 cols: subID,location,valence,RT` do you have any thoughts about why this might be the case? Thank you!

Comment: I tried a number of potential sources of error: valence was character or factor, both of these (surprisingly) worked without issue. Renaming variables resulted in an error. The only thing I can come up with at the moment is that your data does not have the pattern you are looking for. These scripts work for you with the example data, right?

Comment: got it to work! Thank you, your comment about it not having the pattern I'm looking for clued me in (with 80,000 observations the likelihood was 0)...another super beginner mistake - the csv was formatted by the valence category (so of course they were blocked - reorganizing by trial fixed it).